# STRING interactive network in Shiny in R

Tags: javascript, html, r, string, shiny

**Problem Statement:** 
I am trying to load interactive networks of STRING into a Shiny website using R

**What I've Tried:**
According to [STRING](https://string-db.org/cgi/help.pl?sessionId=RnPIpBemDcq9), I can embed the interactive network but I need a couple of elements:

1. Javascript libary

   ```js
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://string-db.org/javascript/combined_embedded_network_v2.0.2.js"></script>
   ```
2. Embed the `div` item

   ```js
   <div id="stringEmbedded"></div>
   ```
3. Call the specific protein with parameters e.g. TP53

   ```js
   getSTRING('https://string-db.org', {'ncbiTaxonId':'9606', 'identifiers':['TP53'], 'network_flavor':'confidence'})"
   ```

In theory, the produced network should be targetted to wherever the `<div id="stringEmbedded"></div>` is placed.

So I did this for Shiny:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Test")
tags$head(HTML("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://string-db.org/javascript/combined_embedded_network_v2.0.2.js'></script>"))

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
menuItem("Item1", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
menuItem("Item2", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th")),
sidebarSearchForm(textId = "searchText", buttonId = "searchButton",label = "Search...") #input$searchText and input$searchButton
))

body <-dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
  tags$body(tags$script(HTML("getSTRING('https://string-db.org', {'ncbiTaxonId':'9606', 'identifiers':['TP53'], 'network_flavor':'confidence'})")),
fluidRow(

    tabBox(
      side = "left", height = "250px",
      selected = "Tab3",
      tabPanel("Tab1", tags$div(id="stringEmbedded")),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2"),
      tabPanel("Tab3", "Note that when side=right, the tab order is reversed.")
    )
  )

ui <- fluidPage(dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body))

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you please make your example more minimal. There are a lot of elements in your shiny app that don't seem necessary. For example, do you need the sidebar, the multiple tabs? The multiple sidebar items? I'm happy to help but that'll be a lot easier if you give a minimal example. Do you even need `shinydashboard` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following my comments from above, here is a minimal working example on how to embed a STRING gene network into a shiny app. I've made use of `shinyjs` which -- while not strictly necessary -- makes working with custom JS code easier.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- "
    shinyjs.loadStringData = function(gene) {
        getSTRING('https://string-db.org', {
            'ncbiTaxonId':'9606',
            'identifiers': gene,
            'network_flavor':'confidence'})
    }"

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
    tags$head(tags$script(src = "http://string-db.org/javascript/combined_embedded_network_v2.0.2.js")),
    textInput("gene", "Gene symbol", value = "TP53"),
    actionButton("button", "Show"),
    h3("Network:"),
    tags$div(id = "stringEmbedded")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    onclick("button", {
        req(input$gene)
        js$loadStringData(input$gene)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked amazingly! thank you for the answer and the feedback for asking better questions

Comment: You're very welcome @SavvasKourtis; I've put together a slightly more polished shiny app on [https://github.com/mevers/shiny_STRING](https://github.com/mevers/shiny_STRING); feel free to clone/modify/change!